# After adding config code in metro config it give an error [react-native-svg-transformer]

Tags: javascript, react-native

`/**`

`Metro configuration for React Native`
`https://github.com/facebook/react-native`
`@Format`
`*/`
`module.exports = {`
`transformer: {`
`getTransformOptions: async () => ({`
`transform: {`
`experimentalImportSupport: false,`
`inlineRequires: true,`
`},`
`}),`
`},`
`};`
`const {getDefaultConfig} = require('metro-config');`
`module.exports = (async () => {`
`const {`
`resolver: {sourceExts, assetExts},`
`} = await getDefaultConfig();`
`return {`
`transformer: {`
`babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),`
`},`
`resolver: {`
`assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),`
`sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],`
`},`
`};`
`})();`

If i remove config code from metro.config.js it is working. And same code is working for react-native (0.67.4) and right now i m trying  it on 0.70.6 version

Comment: Please edit your question. Help others help you by including information like exact error message. This will help others to see the issues, so that they can help you. Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have both packages installed "react-native-svg" and
"react-native-svg-transformer" just replace your metro.config.js with the code below. I hope this will work.

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig();

  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false,
        },
      }),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
  };
})();
```